# Is there a root for Galaxy S7 / S7 edge US Carriers?

Tags: rooting, verizon, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, samsung-galaxy-s7

I recently acquired my Galaxy S7 edge from Verizon and I have yet to find a way to root it? Flashfire? Safestrap? Verizon kinda sucks with this stuff.  I previously had my Galaxy S4 unlocked with the stock android MDK that was on it.

Does anyone know if there is a root for the Verizon S7 Edge yet?  If so can you link a walk through / document one?  I am pretty good with roots I've been doing them for a while, I'm not afraid to use ODIN either.

Thanks,
asloss

UPDATE 6/15/2016:
Turns out there is potential!! http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-s7-edge/how-to/root-unlocked-bootloader-update-t3392841

Comment: Please read [Galaxy S7 Bootloader Lock Explained: You Might Not Get AOSP After All](http://www.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7-bootloader-lock-explained-you-might-not-get-aosp-after-all/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+xda-developers%2FShsH+%28xda-developers%29). It has some pretty good explanation and the root status hasn't changed since then :/ Basic answer is **no**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root is out and a full guide can be found on XDA forums through this link:[root guide and files](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-s7-edge/how-to/verizon-root-knox-t3410624)  This root is for Verizon

Other variants can be found below

[T-Mobile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-s7-edge/how-to/how-to-root-s7-edge-t3410470)

[Sprint](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sprint-s7-edge/how-to/root-t3410424)

[AT&T](http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-s7-edge/how-to/root-available-t3411650)

Verizon:

> http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-...-root-t3410403 Also credits to Mastajeff >for originally making the guide for T-Mobile.
>
> - First off download these files: http://d-h.st/PK3q  Extract them to whatever folder you want, there will be 5 files in there.
> - Folder named: "su" contains the SuperSU and thing needed to root the phone
> - ADB Setup EXE called: "adb-setup-1.4.3.exe" Needed to install ADB and the Drivers
> - Special patched Odin that skips the SHA 225 called: Odin PrinceComsy.exe (Mainly for AT&T)
> - .ini file named: "Odin3.ini"
> - Last, file, named: "Samsung_G935x_QC_Rooted_BOOT.TAR", this is the engBoot for the phone.
>
> NOTE: Some users have experienced endless boot loop; this seems to be
>   caused by using a package disabler that disabled certain services. If
>   you used one and end up getting an endless boot loop try wiping the
>   cache and factory reset the phone.
>
> I suggest you backup your phone before doing this, just in case
>   something happens.
>
> 1. Install ADB by running adb-setup-1.4.3.exe
> 2. Make sure to put your phone into downloading mode (Power off--- Hold Down arrow + Home + Power button)
> 3. Open up Odin and click AP and mount Samsung_G935x_QC_Rooted_BOOT.TAR
> 4. Once restarted put the phone into USB debugging mode (Need Developer options for this)
> 5. To get developer mode, go to "About" then tap "build number" about 6 or 7 times
> 6. Go back to settings and you should now see developer options, turn on USB debugging
> 7. Now back on your PC, Move the folder named "su" into your ADB folder (Default Path: C:\adb)
> 8. Run CMD by either Win + R and typing cmd or from the control panel.
> 9. Once CMD is open type this Code:
>
>    > cd C:\adb\su
>
> or whatever your path to your "su" folder.
>
> 10. After that type root.bat
> 11. Wait for the CMD to finish and then your phone should restart
> 12. Once your phone has finally restarted you will notice that SuperSU was installed and root should be working, download root checker to
>       find out for yourself.
>
> If your CMD just says starting Daemon and doesn't proceed any further
>   than that, then you forgot to make sure USB debugging was turned on.
>   If everything went well you will see the CMD was able to push SuperSU.
>
> You can now install Xposed via Flashfire. Unfortunately, TWRP does not
>   work on this method, so, DO NOT TRY, there is a chance that you can
>   Brick your phone from doing that.
>
> Fix for wifi bug on restart:
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/tmob...8#post67592828
>
> Thanks 2swizzle for mentioning this. If you want to fix the
>   lag/slowness download any CPU or Kernel Editor or changer. This one
>   works fine: https://play.google.com/store/apps/d...ladiutor&hl=en To
>   fix the lag 
>   1. Open up the APP 
>   2. Go into the CPU settings 
>   3. Set CPU Governor to ondemand 
>   4. Apply on boot You will notice that the phone runs fast as ever.

This root is for Verizon and disables Samsung pay.  The root has many variations for all US carriers.

All credit goes to http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4911585 (br3w3r, Chainfire and Princecomsy) and Argyrus for writing up this post